# Custome widget shows "Not Found Error" in Yii2 advanced

Tags: php, yii2, widget, yii2-advanced-app

I have been trying to create a custom widget for my project. I followed [this](https://arjunphp.com/create-custom-widget-yii2/) tutorial to create the widget. Instead of frontend I created the folder in my backend and placed the widget there.
**Folder Path**
*manage\components\contact.php*
and I included the same in my main.php in view/layouts. But I am constantly getting "Not found" error.
[image]

Sharing my sample widget code for your reference.

```
    <?php

namespace manage\components;

use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class Contact extends Widget
{
    public $message;
    public function init()
    {
        // your logic here
        parent::init();
        if ($this->message === null) {
            $this->message = 'Welcome Guest';
        } else {
            $this->message = 'Welcome ' . $this->message;
        }
    }
    public function run()
    {
        // you can load & return the view or you can return the output variable
        return $this->render('contact', ['message' => $this->message]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me what I am missing on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the `@manage` alias to point to your `manage` folder in your configs?

Comment: Yes Please refer the code
<?php
Yii::setAlias('@common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('@frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('@manage', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/manage');
Yii::setAlias('@console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');

Comment: The name of file with class should be `Contact.php` not `contact.php`.

Comment: Tried and failed.

Comment: try use echo manage\components\Contact::widget();  without the first \